# Fullscreen SwipeRefreshLayout with CollapsingToolbar

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, swiperefreshlayout

What I need is that SwipeRefresh animation has to start at the top of the screen inside of CoordinatorLayout with CollapsingToolbar.
If I wrap the RecyclerView inside SwipeRefreshLayout then the animation will start below CollapsingToolbarLayout.
If I wrap the whole CoordinatorLayout inside SwipeRefreshLayout then the behavior won't be very precise and it won't work out of the first swipe.

Here is the layout where SwipeRefresh animation is shown below the CollapsingToolbar:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<net.telekom.smartcity.custom.OscaAppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/services_toolbar_height"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/white"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@id/marketplaceToolbar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/zoomableImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="matrix"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

        <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/black35a"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/services_toolbar_title_top_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/services_toolbar_infobox_margin_start"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/marketplace_toolbar_message1"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/services_toolbar_title_size"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/services_toolbar_title_padding_bottom"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    style="@style/RobotoBold"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/services_toolbar_title_description_top_margin"
                    android:text="@string/services_toolbar_message2"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/services_toolbar_description_size"
                    style="@style/RobotoLight"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/marketplaceToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="false">
            <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/toolbarCityBox"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_gravity="start">

                <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/toolbarCoat"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/toolbar_coa_size"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_coa_size"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/toolbar_title_size"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        style="@style/RobotoMedium"
                />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</net.telekom.smartcity.custom.OscaAppBarLayout>


<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: please add xml code

Comment: @AntonisRadz added

Comment: one not very clean option is to use two SwipeRefreshLayouts. One as container for CoordinatorLayout for showing loader another as an actual swipe to refresh layout and pass events one to other. Another option is  like you did with wrapping everything in SwipeRefreshLayout and just fix focus. And the cleanest one is just to implement custom loader view and bind it to SwipeRefreshLayout events